# python3 -m build ... supply version number via command line argument

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I use `python3 -m build` to build my python package like documented in the official docs: [Packaging Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives).

But I don't want to store my version number in the source code, because this creates too many useless changes in the git repository.

Is there a way to leave `version` empty in `setup.cfg` and provide the version via the `python3 -m build` command line?

I use the recommended `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Related question in the Python Forum: https://discuss.python.org/t/avoid-having-version-number-in-source-code/10188

Related issue: https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/347

Comment: _`build`_ is the build front-end, and what you are asking for would be a feature of the "build back-end". Your build back-end is apparently _`setuptools`_, so you could use something like [_`setuptools-scm`_](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) to get the version number via git tag for example, this way you would not need to write the version number in any file directly. --  As far as I know it is not possible to pass a version string to the build tool. Maybe with `--config-setting` but I do not know any back-end that uses this for version string.

Comment: I don't want to use setuptools_scm, since I don't get the version number from the git repo.

Comment: Well, without something like setuptools-scm, I have no idea. Maybe there is a build back-end that would take the version string via build's [_`--config-setting`_](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#python--m-build---config-setting), but I don't know any. -- Maybe relevant: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
import os
setup(version=os.environ.get('BUILD_VERSION'))
```

Call build like this:

```
BUILD_VERSION=... python3 -m build
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could get is with a command like the following for a *`setuptools`* build back-end:

```
python -m build \
--config-setting=--global-option=egg_info \
--config-setting=--global-option=--tag-build=SUFFIX
```

This adds a suffix to the version string.

So if you set the version string to `1` in `setup.cfg` and `SUFFIX` to `.2.3` on the command line, you would get `1.2.3`.

This is a hack but seems to work well enough. Tested with:

- *Python 3.6.9*
- *build 0.6.0.post1*
- *setuptools 58.0.2*

No guarantee it will continue to work in the foreseeable future. For a longer term solution, maybe it might be worth keeping an eye on and/or weighing in this [setuptools feature request](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2491).

***References***:

- https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#python--m-build---config-setting
- https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/328#issuecomment-877028239
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html#tagging-and-daily-build-or-snapshot-releases